# .htaccess using HTTP_HOST has one extra extraneous redirect when forcing HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https

When I use these lines in my `.htaccess` file, everything works well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[image]

Then I tried to make it work without manually writing the domain in the URL and tried these lines instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But now there is an additional redirect when reached from www without https:

[image]

I don't understand why, I just replaced the domain with `{HTTP_HOST}`. When I do that, it redirects from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` (since it is my main domain) then `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`

If I add this line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` it does not change anything.

Why does it behave like that and how can I fix the `.htaccess` file to not having to manually write the URL and directly redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`?

Comment: I do not see a "too many redirects" errors in your screenshot. On the contrary all tests end in HTTP code 200 which is what you want. After that it also depends on where your `.htaccess` file is stored and how your `example.com` and `www.example.com` `VirtualHost` are configured, but you do not show.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, indeed there is not a true error but after that I modified the htaccess there is an additional (and unwanted) redirect. I updated my post to make it more clear. I use a shared hosting from OVH, the `.htaccess file` and the website files are both stored in `/root folder/www/`, www. subdomain is just an alias in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to remove the `www.` from the host name then you should use your first set of rules that contain the domain name.   That is because the `{HTTP_HOST}` variable contains the full host name including any subdomains.   So when the site is accessed with `http://www.example.com` the `HTTP_HOST` is `www.example.com`.   When you use that variable in the redirect, the `www.` is included.

If you really object to hard-coding your domain name in that rewrite rule, it might be possible to switch from `HTTP_HOST` to `SERVER_NAME`.   The server name variable can be made to be your preferred host name as specified in your virtual host configuration, but only if `UseCanonicalName on` is on there as well.  See [What is the difference between HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/what-is-the-difference-between-http-host-and-server-name-in-php)   Your virtual host configuration would have to be:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    UseCanonicalName on
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You may not have such fine grain control over your virtual host directive.   Many hosting packages such as cPanal and WHM write the config for you and don't let you modify it.  I'd recommend sticking with your hard-coded domain name in your rewrite rule because it is easy to do and it works.

Comment: Thank you Stephen Ostermiller, that explains why I have not been able to find a solution, you provided a good explanation here. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** There is something else in your code base that is redirecting. The directives you have posted in the question do not (fully) explain the output you are seeing. In fact, the directives you posted from your `.htaccess` file may not even be getting processed at all...

(This answer is really in addition to @Stephen's answer and attempts to explain - or question - the results you are seeing.)

> When I use these lines in my `.htaccess` file, everything works well:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

"everything works well" - Well, these directives can only be responsible for the first two scenarios you mention (ie. *from HTTP*):

- `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`
- `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`

However, these directives won't redirect from `https://www` (third scenario), as you appear to suggest. They don't canonicalise the www subdomain. ***Something else* is performing this redirection.**

> I just replaced the domain with `{HTTP_HOST}`. When I do that, it redirects from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` (since it is my main domain) then `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`.

**Given the directive you posted; this is impossible!** Your directive only ever redirects to `https`, so "something else" must be triggering the first redirect you are seeing to `http`. (But there should be nothing that occurs before your `.htaccess` redirect - other than in the main server config, or possibly another `.htaccess` file, but I assume nothing like that has changed?)

It's possible you are seeing a *cached* redirect, but you say that you "just replaced the domain with `{HTTP_HOST}`", so that kind of rules out the cache.

> If I add this line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` it does not change anything.

Well, that should definitely have changed the additional redirect you were seeing above (assuming you added it somewhere before the `RewriteRule` directive). So, if this didn't do anything then it further suggests that **"something else" is performing these redirects and perhaps your directives are not being processed at all!**

However, you're suggesting that this additional redirect only started after you "replaced the domain with `{HTTP_HOST}`" - which appears to be impossible. So, **something else must also have changed**.

---

Some of this could be explained with having placed these directives in the wrong order in your `.htaccess` file. For example, if you were using WordPress (or another CMS that uses a *front-controller* pattern) and you placed your redirects at the end of the file then for most page requests it won't get processed. But, depending on your config, it might still get processed for your homepage and your static resources.

Any redirects of this nature need to go at the very start of your `.htaccess`.

And make sure you are not mixing mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) directives with mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`. This can result in unexpected conflicts.

---

> ...how can I fix the `.htaccess` file to not having to manually write the URL and directly redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`?

*Aside:* If you are intending to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) then, ironically, you'll need to redirect in two steps (using `HTTP_HOST` as above). The first redirect goes to HTTPS *on the same host*, optionally followed by a canonical www/non-www redirect on HTTPS.

To redirect in a single redirect, you don't necessarily need to use the server-config as @Stephen suggests in his answer (although that is a possibility). But if you have access to the server config then there are altogether better ways to do this using mod_alias `Redirect` and `<VirtualHost>` containers (quicker and arguably "simpler") - no need for mod_rewrite at all.

However, you can implement this as a single redirect (both HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www) in `.htaccess` using something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The above states... for all requests that are either not-HTTPS *or* where the requested *hostname* starts `www.` then redirect to `https://<hostname-less-www-prefix>/<URL-path>`. This also removes an optional trailing dot in the case of FQDN. The third *condition* is necessary in order to capture the hostname, less the (optional) `www.` prefix. This is captured into the `%1` backreference.

Note that the above is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect after you have done your testing and confirmed that it is working OK (to avoid caching issues fogging your tests).

Generalising the directives in this way isn't always the best (or most reliable) solution across systems.